# Android change previous activity theme

Tags: android, themes

I want change hole application theme and i can do it and handle this by saving in `sharedPreference` and set theme in my `BaseActivity`.
Changing theme is in separate activity, but when i go back to previous activity it has not updated theme.but if i close the application and reopen or move to unopened activity, theme changed.
I tried to set theme in `onResume` but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theme can only be set before setContentView() is called in your Activity. You can try something like calling recreate() after updating your theme, but I would advise against that.

Here are some popular theming libraries that handle these things for you:

[Aesthetic](https://github.com/afollestad/aesthetic)

[Colorful](https://github.com/garretyoder/Colorful)

[Magica Sakura](https://github.com/Bilibili/MagicaSakura)